# TCP user timeout option

Tags: tcp, linux

How can i set TCP option 28 (user timeout option) into the TCP header? 
i'm trying to send TCP packet between two Linuxes via HPING (If there is a better tool which will help to set TCP option 28 please tell me), and till now i didn't success to set the user timeout option. (I'm looking into the sniffer and the option 28 didn't exist).

Comment: You need an application to do this, but recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigations to tcp injection tools,
I found that SCAPY is the best one which helped me to inject the options i need into the tcp header.